# Will this NGS data annotation code pipeline work?

Tags: java, shell, cpu, pipeline

```
threads=36
task() {
        NEWNAME="${1/%.norm.vcf.gz/.snv.indel.vcf.gz}"
        java -Xmx8g -jar /home/ubuntu/snpEff/SnpSift.jar annotate /home/ubuntu/data/spliceai_scores.raw.snv.hg19.vcf.gz $1 | java -Xmx8g -jar /home/ubuntu/snpEff/SnpSift.jar annotate /home/ubuntu/data/spliceai_scores.raw.indel.hg19.vcf.gz > $NEWNAME1
    }

for file in $(ls *norm.vcf.gz)
do
    if [ $(jobs -r | wc -l) -ge $threads ]; then
            wait $(jobs -r -p | head -1)
    fi
    task "$file" &
done
wait
```

I am now learning NGS pipeline and I would like to annotate two DBs(snv,indel) using SnpSift. Currently I am using 36 threads CPU. Since there are two commands in task() function, annotate snv and indel, will my code wait $(jobs -r -p | head -1) work fine?
Are there any other recommendations to use CPU efficiently?